# To find the probability that the ant passes through the element $a_{23}$?

Tags: probability, matrices

In a matrix $A_4\times_4$ , an ant starts moving from $a_{11}$ in such a way that it can move from $a_{ij}$ to either $a_{(i+1)j}$ or  $a_{(j+1)i}$ in one step. If it reaches $a_{44}$, the probability that it passes through $a_{23}$ .

what I tried is starting from $a_{11}$ it have 2 possibilities to move from  $a_{11}$ to $a_{12}$ or $a_{21}$ and from these two points again it have two possibilities  and again two possibilities but can't find any way to proceed further

Comment: _Hint_: draw out a matrix with the number of ways the ant could get to each square.

Comment: Is the answer $5/16$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $\frac9{20}$

Answer (score 0):

The total number of paths is $\binom{6}{3}=20$ and the number of such paths that pass through $a_{2,3}$ is $\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}=9$.

Hence the answer is $\frac{9}{20}$

Comment: Can you add some details ? As why total paths are 20 and total ways of passing through a23 9

Comment: @Jorge Fernández Hidalgo please add some details

Answer (score 0):

After $5$ steps, we have one of the following options:

- RRRRD ($5$ ways)
- RRRDD ($10$ ways)
- RRDDD ($10$ ways)
- RDDDD ($5$ ways)

$30$ ways in total, $10$ arrive at $a_{2,3}$, so the probability is $\frac13$.